# Canon EDSDK - Multiple cameras - Take photo simultaneously

Tags: c#, wpf, edsdk, canon-sdk

I am using this library: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp

I have multiple cameras (Canon EOS 1300D). I load them with API:

```
CanonAPI canonAPI = new CanonAPI();
List<Camera> cameras = canonAPI.GetCameraList();
```

then I make some settings (to save files in PC, not in cameras and open session). After that I want to make multiple Photos at once. Like as close to each other. Right now all I can think of is this:

```
foreach (Camera camera in cameras)
{
    camera.TakePhotoAsync();
}
```

Sadly, this approach has a little delay. But in multiple cameras (5) that delay is somewhat 200-300ms (I think, don't remember), and that is too big.

Another info: For taking photo I use WPF and button. Cameras are connected through usb hub, have no SD card and I am saving photos directly to computer. Everything works, I need to take photos at once.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Parallel loop

```
Parallel.ForEach(cameras , camera =>
{
     //Your stuff
});
```

be careful using Parallel loops while using files and threads.
you can read about [Parallel loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx)

Comment: Well, never heard of that - will try. It takes some time to connect cameras etc. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this works much better. There is still some tiny delay. I suppose that will never be better. I will try with multiple cameras (right now I have only two for testing).

Comment: @Stepan, there will always be a delay because of the way the Canon SDK works. Commands have to be executed in serial, even with multiple cameras. I'm working on a successor of the library you use which could help in your case. If you are interested in trying it, use the contact form on my homepage, you can find the link on my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: Thanks, today I wanted to tell you that it didn't help. Parallel was just making photos in chaotic order, but still one by one. I will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the serial execution delay issue in my project, I connected the remote shutter wires in parallel between multiple cameras.  I then used a USB relay to trigger the remote shutter wires to take the pictures simultaneously and used the downloadReady event to download the images.